# JasperReportsの文字化けについて

Tags: java

はじめまして
開発環境EclipseにおいてGUI計算プログラムを作成しています。(javaFX)
プログラムの結果を帳票ツールのJasperReportを利用して出力することが目的です。

テンプレートとしたjrxmlを用意して、JavaのBeanクラスからデータを渡しています。
java側で動的にjrxmlをコンパイルし、printをJasperViewerで表示する形です。
また、データには、日本語文字列、数字など様々な値をすべてStringクラスでフィールド設定しています。テンプレートのフィールドテキストは、MSゴシックを選択しています。

このソースを開発環境上で、はしらせた場合にはViewerで表示がされ希望通りの結果となります。（日本語の出力も可）

しかし、このプロジェクトをEclipseで、build.fxbuildを用いて、
build.xmlを作成してインストーラーを作成し、windowsへインストールした場合、beanから取得されたフィールド値が文字化けします。（日本語のみ）

Stringクラスの保持する文字コードだろうと思い
予め文字コードを宣言して下記をbeanのセッターメソッドへ追記しました。

```
    new String(String.getBytes()."UTF-8")
```

結果は再度ビルドしなおしても変わらずでした。

以下個人的に考察した事項です。

・コンパイル時にbeanメンバのString（UTF-16?）の文字コードが変わってしまうのか
・そもそも変換の仕方が違うのか
・jrxml側のフィールドテキストでエンコード指定ができるのか

などですが、１日中ググっても解決に至らずお手上げ状態です。

みなさんご教授お願い致します。

追記

プログラミングは、家のノートとデスクトップでやっていまして、デスクトップ(win10)ではeclipseでシステムエンコーディングはutf-8、eclipseワークスペース設定も同様でした。
ノート(win7)の確認が取れてませんが、怪しい可能性があります。

どこかで見た内容ですが、
eclipseのワークスペースでutf-8等文字コードを設定しても、別の環境で作成または編集保存をしたjavaファイルを、eclipseがコンパイルするときに別の文字コードで実行してまう。
事実であれば、別環境(別デフォルトエンコーディング)でプログラムしていることで、文字コードが混在した状況なのかもしれません。

Comment: `new String(String.getBytes()."UTF-8")`と言うのはJavaのコードとして意味をなしませんが、`new String(value.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`(`value`は`String`型)と言ったコードをBeanの全ての文字型のセッターに追加したと言うことでしょうか?だとしたら今すぐやめた方が良いでしょう。文字コードについて何も知らない人が使う典型的なバッドコードの例です。文字化けの理由が特定の限られたものである場合に文字化けが解消する可能性がありますが、その他(「その他」の方が圧倒的に多い)の場合、元の文字化けは解消しない上に正しい文字列を文字化けさせてしまう可能性の方が高い極めて困ったコードです。原因は、Eclipseから起動した時のJavaのデフォルトエンコーディングとインストールしたものを実行する時のJavaのデフォルトエンコーディングが異なっているせい、と言う可能性が高いように思います。`getBytes()`の他にも、デフォルトエンコーディングに依存する処理があちこちに散りばめられていると言う可能性が高いのではないですか?まずは双方の環境のデフォルトエンコーディングを確かめてみてください。

Comment: コメントへの返信ありがとうございます。調べてわかった情報は、随時ご質問を「編集」して、ご質問本文に追記していただくと、コメントよりも多くの読者に読みやすくなりますし、アクティブリストの上位に置かれるので、あなたのご質問の存在をアピールすることにもなります。(ご自身の質問は「編集」出来るはずです。)また例えば「JavaのBeanクラス」に値を入れる部分の処理なんかもコードで示していただけると、環境依存で文字化けする可能性のある部分を指摘することが出来るかもしれません。編集機能もうまく利用して、早く問題が解決できれば良いですね。